# About how to send and receive a PUT request with Jersey

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I followed the answer in

[Post/Put/Delete http Json with additional parameters in Jersey + general design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430270/post-put-delete-http-json-with-additional-parameters-in-jersey-general-design)

But I continued to get `400 Bad Request`... Any idea how to solve this problem?

Here is what I have for jersey restful server:

```
@PUT
@Path("/insertmessage")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
public Response insertMessage(Message m) {
    return Response.ok(m.toString(), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
}
```

here is what I have for client:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Message("a", "b", "message"));
System.out.print(service.path("insertmessage")
       .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).put(String.class, json));
```

Here is the constructor for message:

```
@JsonCreator
public Message(@JsonProperty("sender") String sender,
               @JsonProperty("receiver") String receiver,
               @JsonProperty("content") String content) {
    this.sender = sender;
    this.receiver = receiver;
    this.content = content;
}
```

And I have:

```
<init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

in my web.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jersey 2.x you can use proxy-client so you can call a service as if it is local class.
As to your code it is unclear what is controller annotation and path. I am talking about this part **path("rest")**.

Comment: My appology, that is a typo... I am using Jersey 1.18. My question is how can I send a Object to the server and how can the server receive this Object. Currently Im using Jackson to serialize the Object, but it  keeps showing me 400 error

Comment: If you have **POJO_MAPPING** set you don't need to map objects explicitly. And you even don't need to annotate Message class. Considering **getBaseURI()** returns correct value it should work. Check your server with curl or other hand controlled client. 400 means you have an error in http request itself not in json. And I do recommend Jersey 2.x as 1.x is messy. You will not need all this buggy String literals, Response building, etc.

Comment: By "you don't need to map objects explicitly", you mean I dont need to use Jackson to explicitly serialize the object but send the Object itself directly instead?

Comment: Yes, you just pass your object to put(). Jersey should convert it to proper mime type by itself. If my mind doesn't fail me ;)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it once I have time.